# Tyk API Gateway keeps retrying the request every 60 sec

Tags: java, microservices, api-gateway, retry-logic, tyk

I have a request that sometimes needs more than a minute to execute.
My service is behind Tyk API Gateway. What happens is that after the request is being executed by the service for 60 sec, Tyk sends the same request again to the service ignoring the first one. From the client perspective, it's all the same requests that run about 5 min (because in fact there are 5 requests).

I tried to invoke it directly by IP (without the) and there are no retries.
I also tried to add hard_timeouts to tyk equal to 2 min, but the request keeps retrying.
I don't see any other configs that may be related to this.

Even though I am going to optimize this request or make it asynchronous, I am looking for a more quick solution now. Do you have some idea how to stop this retry functionality?

Comment: https://community.tyk.io/t/http-proxy-error-context-canceled/2767/10 it might be related. I also see this error.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it's nginx problem that needs to be resolved. Since the question has a bounty, I can't close it. Here is the nginx related one:
[nginx keeps retrying request every 60 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222655/nginx-keeps-retrying-request-every-60-sec)